# „… das bleibt am Ende das Einzige …“ Ich verstehe die grammatische Struktur nicht ganz

Tags: sentence-structure

> Auch über andere Mächtige wird gelacht. Kölner aber sind kaum Ziel der
> Späße – höchstens der Fußballklub, wenn er wieder einmal verloren hat.
> Mehr würde das Fernsehpublikum, das in ganz Deutschland zuschaut,
> nicht verstehen. 
>  Becker ist die Verbindung zu Köln für seine
> zukünftigen Büttenredner aber trotzdem wichtig. Denn **das bleibt am
> Ende das Einzige**, was die Büttenreden noch von der Comedy
> unterscheidet. Deshalb sagt er: Wer einen Witz über die
> Bundeskanzlerin erzählt, sollte auch den Kölner Bürgermeister nicht
> vergessen.
>
> Deutsch Perfekt, 2013 (2), S. 16.

In dem Satzteil, den ich Fett markiert habe, ist das Subjekt meiner Meinung nach "das". Und das Verb "bleiben" ist ein intransitives Verb. "das Einzige" ist also kein Akkusativobjekt. Aber was ist das denn?

Wenn ein "als" vor "das Einzige" gestanden hätte, hätte ich den Satz für problemlos gehalten. Aber sonst ist der Satz für mich schwer grammatisch klar zu verstehen. Kann jemand mir helfen?

Comment: „Das“ bezieht sich auf den Satz davor, also die Verbindung zu Köln. Sie, diese Verbindung, ist es, die als Einziges bleibt. Ich würde das als prädikativen oder „Gleichsetzungsnominativ“ betrachten: Die Verbindung bleibt das Einzige. Mit „bleiben“ ist die Konstruktion nicht so häufig, mit „seien“ ist sie gang & gäbe: Der Mann ist ein Riese.

Comment: Vielen Dank für den Kommentar, Ingmar. Mein erster Gedanke war auch, dass "das Einzige" etwas Ähnliches wie "ein Riese" in Ihrem Beispielssatz. 
"Der Mann" = "ein Riese"  


Ich war mir nicht sicher, ob das Verb "bleiben" auch so ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ haben kann wie das Verb "sein", weil ich in keinem Wörterbuch so einen Beispielssatz finden konnte. Ihrer Meinung nach ist das also auch beim Verb "bleiben" wohl möglich und der Satz, der mich irritiert hat, wäre ein Beispiel dafür…

Comment: Genau. Wobei die meisten Muttersprachler diese Konstruktion vermutlich gar nicht benennen könnten (und das ja für das Verständnis auch keine Rolle spielt.)

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/50530/) in englisch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt nicht nur Akkusativobjekte im Deutschen. Jeder Kasus kann als Verb-Ergänzung stehen, abhängig vom verwendeten Verb:

- Ich sehe dich. (Akkusativ)
- Ich vertraue ihr. (Dativ)
- Wir gedenken der Vermißten. (Genitiv)
- Das bleibt ein Problem. (Nominativ)

Die Nominativergänzung ist allerdings die seltenste und tritt nur mit 'sein', 'werden', 'bleiben', 'scheinen' und verwandten Verben auf.

Comment: Dankr für Ihre Antwort, Herr Foth! Das Verb "bleiben" kann also eine Nominativergänzung haben. Das wusste ich nicht und Ihre Antwort vermittelte mir dieses wichtige Wissen. Mir wurde viel geholfen. Danke schön!